# Problems in an unconventional encryption scheme?

Tags: encryption, hash, aes

My program includes a feature where users could encrypt certain data using a password. As not all passwords will be a proper length, are there any insecurities in fixing this by hashing the password (with a good algorithm) to generate a fixed-length key which will then be fed into AES?

EDIT: Never mind, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function

Comment: Only in that shorter passwords will be easier to brute-force by someone who has the salt and your algorithm. If you get the rest right, I can't see anything else wrong. Normally you compute hash of (salt + password) repeated 60 times or something so that the actual length of the password isn't that significant.

Comment: Thank you, my research turned out to be fruitful only seconds after your comment.

Answer (score 2):

If password is easy to break because it is short - hashing it will not help as all what will be needed is to apply the same hash function during brute force attack. And it may not be possible to make hash function completely secret as it must be exposed at some point to hash the password.

Comment: These seem to be problems universal to the more common hash algorithms.

Comment: They are not problems on the hash algorithms, they are problems relating to password management and use. Most secure hash algorithms are fine.